# How to send location via intent.putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent, location

I have a problem, I have a main activity, which have a `locationlistener`, and I want to use this location info (like `location.getAccuracy()` or `location.getAltitude()`) in different activity.
What is better solution, implement new `locationListener` in new activity or send location using `intent.putExtra` ?

Comment: I recommend SharedPrefereces for this.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2736612/940096)

Comment: If the `Location` class implements `Parcelable` you cut put it in the `Intent` as an extra. You should try to get locations via a `Service` though, but that's just my thought.